# Invalid configuration object error from Webpack 2.4.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've been trying to compile my React app with Webpack and I received an error:

> configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties
>   are valid:    object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?,
>   descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?,
>   extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?,
>   modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?,
>   useSyncFileSystemCalls?

I am sure my files in the directory are in the correct place. Here is the rundown of both `webpack.config.js` and `package.json`:

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "webpack_practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practicing webpack setup",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: { 
     root: __dirname,      
     alias: {
      Greeter: 'public/components/Greeter.jsx',
      GreeterMessage: 'public/components/GreeterMessage.jsx',
      GreeterForm: 'public/components/GreeterForm.jsx'
    },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/   
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

The error started when I added the alias under resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`resolve.root` is a webpack 1 option - which has been deprecated now. You are encouraged to use webpack 2 (which is what your package.json shows).

Referring to: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-root-resolve-fallback-resolve-modulesdirectories, you can see that the option was removed in favor of the option `modules`.

Comment: May I ask how would you rewrite and substitute alias with  modules features? What woulf web.config.js above would have look like? Please keep in mind, I'm new at WebPack.